# Store textbox value as it showing in database

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

In my php page I set the format for the text box like first character capital and else as user enter it.Works good for the front end but for back end when it goes to the db it insert as a simple text.I want it like to insert in db as it shows in the ui.

Jquery that i use to formating the textbox'text

```
$(".initial_cap").keydown(function(){
        console.log("aaa");
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val.length==1)
        {
            val = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() ;
            $(this).val(val);
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<input class="form-control initial_cap" placeholder="Address1" required="required" maxlength="50" name="address1" type="text" value="" aria-required="true">
```

EX: when I enter anything lets say helloword my function will convert it to Helloword and set as value of textbox then why in database it inserted as helloword.

Comment: Add all the parts of your code please. not just the _Works good_ part

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

Comment: Its just  this much that will change the text to first character capital and when form submit it post the entered text not a formated text.now the question is why it do not post the text as it is in value.